# GoogleApiClient.Builder.enableAutoManage() giving me an error

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get google sign in working, and I ran into this error:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                 this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

`this` is wrong because it wants an `OnConnectionFailedListener` object, not an `Activity`.

So I cast it to `OnConncetionFailedListener`:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                (GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

Which removes the red squigglys. But when I run the app, the app crashes, and the error I get is:

```
09-02 13:01:37.937    2403-2403/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.googlelogin, PID: 2403
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.googlelogin/com.example.android.googlelogin.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.googlelogin.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.googlelogin.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
            at com.example.android.googlelogin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Which basically says that I cannot cast an `Activity` to an `OnConncetionFailedListener`.

What do I do to correct this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are casting your `Activity` to `OnConnectionFailedListener`, but it does *not* implement that interface.

Either make `FragmentActivity` implement `OnConnectionFailedListener` (the explicit cast can be omitted in this case), or subclass `OnConnectionFailedListener` and pass an instance of that class instead of your `Activity`.

The simpliest solution might be to use an anonymous inner class:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                // connection failed, should be handled
            }
        })
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a class which implements the `OnConnectionFailedListener` interface. There several ways to do this:

1. Change your activity to `MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnConnectionFailedListener`.
2. Create a new class `MyConnectionFailedListener implements OnConnectionFailedListener`.
3. Define an anonymous inner class directly in your code:

   ```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
       .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
           new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
               // methods go here
           }
       .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
       .build();
   ```

Now provide code for all methods declared by `OnConnectionFailedListener`. Most likely the tutorial you are following used the first approach. Personally, I prefer the third if there are few methods and each method has only a few lines (less than 5). If the code for `OnConnectionFailedListener` is too complex, I will use option 2 with a descriptive name for the new class.

Comment: `enableAutoManage()` expects a `FragmentActivity`, so passing an `Activity` instance to it will not work. (`FragmentActivity` is a subclass of `Activity` and not the other way around)

Comment: @user13 I intended `FragmentActivity` as the name of the OP's activity class. I forgot that this name is used in the Support Library. I have edited my answer to (hopefully) be more clear.

Comment: implementing OnConnectionListener in your Activity class does the trick